# Is it a good idea to combine all the css within an application into one css file?

Tags: php, css, symfony

I have different css files for different modules in my Symfony based application. My client asked me to combine them into one single css file. Is that really a good idea? What way it may impact on my application?

Comment: For production: yes; for development: no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is a good idea, because that way, visitor will have to download only one file, which is more efficient.

For from a developer point of view, different files can be more convenient, though.

So often, people will develop multiple separate CSS files, and they have a script that combines these files into one file for deployment.

Two additional steps you can do are

1. minimize the CSS files by removing whitespace and comments. This will make the download even smaller and even more efficient. Again, you would do this through a script, not by hand. You don't develop in minimizes CSS files, and you certainly don't want to waste time removing comments by hand.
2. use [SCSS](http://sass-lang.com/guide) or another 'smart' CSS language, so your development CSS files can be smarter and more structured. The SCSS (or SASS or LESS) files are compiled into one final CSS file. Often this compilation will be combined with minification too. Compilation is necessary, because browsers only know 'plain' CSS, not SCSS.

Tip: there are scripts (PHP scripts, mostly) that can do these steps on the fly. Don't use them, because they will have overhead to. Make the minification part of your deployment process. Develop locally, compile and minify on deploy, and let the live environment use the static, minified CSS file.

Comment: Although do make sure to test compiled before deployment.

Comment: Thanks Golez, I totally agree with you. I had came across a project long time back where I saw the use of SCSS but could not figure out how to use that or what is the importance of that.Anyways, I'll check it out now.